# Settings UICollectionViewFlowLayout's properties not working when using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uicollectionview

I'm trying to set up a *UICollectionView* with a *UICollectionViewFlowLayout* with the following requirement: the *minimumLineSpacing* should always be exactly one-third of the height of the *UICollectionView*. My initial thought was to override *viewDidLayoutSubviews* like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = collectionView.frame.height / 3
    collectionViewFlowLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Note that I use *viewDidLayoutSubviews* because I'm planning to use Auto Layout and the frame may depend on some complex constraints. So I can't calculate the frame myself but have to wait until Auto Layout calculated it for me to use in *viewDidLayoutSubviews*.

I tested this a bit by creating a *UICollectionView* programmatically (and rotating the simulator to see if the *minimumLineSpacing* is always correct). It seemed to work just fine.

Then, I switched to Auto Layout. I simply constrained the collection view's top, bottom, leading and trailing space to its superview. After doing so, setting the *minimumLineSpacing* didn't have the intended effect anymore, it simply didn't change anything about the appearance of the collection view.

The following code nicely demonstrates the issue. As soon as I set `useAutoLayout` to `true`, setting the *minimumLineSpacing* doesn't work anymore.

```
class DemoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var collectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

    // MARK: - UIViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
        collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.dataSource = self

        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        let useAutoLayout = false // Change this to true to test!

        if useAutoLayout {
            collectionView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[collectionView]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView" : collectionView]))
            NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[collectionView]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView" : collectionView]))
        } else {
            collectionView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleWidth
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = collectionView.frame.height / 3
        collectionViewFlowLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }

    // MARK: - <UICollectionViewDataSource>

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        return cell
    }

}
```

Test this code in the Simulator, rotate it and see how setting the *minimumLineSpacing* doesn't do anything when `useAutoLayout` is set to `true`. So my question is: How can I use Auto Layout and still provide a *minimumLineSpacing*?

**Notes**
*Base SDK* is set to *iOS 8.4 SDK*. Setting other properties like `itemSize` or `minimumInteritemSpacing` doesn't work either.

Comment: Rather than using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, have you tried providing the delegate method `- collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced what you describe. It's very strange.

I think there is something about rotation specifically that causes `invalidLayout()` to be ignored in this context. Perhaps the problem is that your call to `invalidateLayout()` occurs at a point where the layout object thinks it has already responded, or is in the process of responding, to the layout invalidation automatically produced by the rotation and consequent bounds change of the collection view. Then your invalidation is ignored, because it comes too late to be coalesced into the automatic one, and too soon to count as a separate invalidation. I'm guessing. I notice that you can even keep incrementing the `minimumLineSpacing` there, and it will happily march up to infinity without the collection view ever having the wit to do layout again.

But if you set up the view controller so that a shake event triggers the invalidation, then it notices the value.

So you can solve the problem by forcing the invalidation to happen at the next turn of the run loop, thus escaping whatever weird special logic is blocking it during rotation. For instance, if you replace your `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` with the following:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

  let newValue = collectionView.bounds.height / 3
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    [weak collectionViewFlowLayout] in
    collectionViewFlowLayout?.minimumLineSpacing = newValue
  }
```

then it works.

Why should this be necessary? I don't know. I don't think it should be necessary. This feels like a bug in `UICollectionView` to me, or at least a very unintuitive piece of API.

Comment: Thanks for your help. While I don't really like the dispatch_async workaround, I agree it's the only thing I can do right now. I already suspected this was a bug so I filed a radar (https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5081000568684544)

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the workaround either, because it doesn't feel like it should be necessary! But there may be no "correct" solution if UIKit itself is what is incorrect.